# How To Draw A Flower In Android Each Petal By Petal

Tags: java, android

In android I would like to draw flower by adding each petal from a center point. I used setRotation on the image view but the center point is different for each petal. (I mean the center point from the flower) Can anybody look at my code and suggest me correction? Thanks.

```
   int angle=0;
   int ypos=500;
   int xpos=500;

   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ln1);

   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {

      ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
      image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150,400));
      image.setX(xpos);
      image.setY(ypos);
      image.setPadding(-7,-30,-10,0);
      image.setPivotX(1.0f);
      image.setScaleX(1.5f);
      image.setScaleY(1.5f);

      image.setImageResource(R.drawable.petal);
      image.setRotation(image.getRotation() + angle);
      angle=angle+36;
      layout.addView(image);
   }
```

Image I get is this

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "the center point _is_ different for each petal", or "the center point _should be_ different for each petal"? (In the latter case, I'd assume you meant the center point of the petal, rather than the center point of the flower). Either way, I think you're missing a translation - adding a bit to the x and y values for each individual petal.

Comment: Yes center point from the flower

Comment: Can you post an image link or something to ilustrate what you imagine the end result would be?

Comment: Yes I have edited the question and added the image I am getting. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is the right snippet? If your angle was increased _before_ the call to `setRotation`, then I would expect this image. And, I suppose the petal in the image itself is "upright", it's not that the original image itself is rotated?

Comment: It is difficult without knowing how the original image looks like. I have the impression you should start with another angle. Perhaps angle=-36. If that doesn't work, try other starting angles.

Comment: Angle is incremented after setRotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you rotate the image, the rotation is done with the top left corner of the image, not the center of the rotated image.

Below image might illustrate this. The black square represents your image. The lefthand site shows the situation you have now. The righthand side shows the situation you want.

[image]

Before rotating, you should subtract half the width from the x position, and add half the height from the y position. Then you should get the desired image.

As user Ralf Renz pointed out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795145/how-to-draw-a-flower-in-android-each-petal-by-petal/49795659#comment86605147_49795145), you could also simply start with an angle of -36. This is a useful workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Let me try this out.

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this using the following strategy.

```
image.setPivotY(-1);
```

Now the flower was coming in a different design because petal was Tilted. So I Tilted my actual image to the opposite direction using inkscape and now I get the desired output.

[image]